# How to use groupby on the following dataset

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this dataset,

```
sender          team_id     receiver
John Cena         1           Margaret
Genghis Khan      2           Mahathma
Mahathma Gandhi   1           John
John Doe          2           Genghis
Margaret Thatcher 1           John
```

Each sender has a team id and receiver's name is only their first name. I want to find out if each message is between team members or not. The result would look something like this.

```
sender          team_id     receiver       btwn_teammates
John Cena         1           Margaret          Yes
Genghis Khan      2           Mahathma          No
Mahathma Gandhi   1           John              Yes
John Doe          2           Genghis           Yes
Margaret Thatcher 1           John              Yes
```

Comment: How do you resolve the ambiguity of sending to `John`, which could be either `John Cena` or `John Doe`? In the last row, the full name of `John Cena` is provided, violating the assumption that `receiver` only ever contains a first name. In general, what system is logging only the recipient's first name, and could you change it to record their full name instead?

Comment: Should John Doe and Ghengis be Yes?

Comment: Sorry about that. The dataset is already there and I can't change it. Teams have at most 10 people in it. There is no 2 people with same first name in a team. It does not need to be 100% accurate. As long as it is close enough to the result table, it's totally fine.

Comment: @Lollz Yes. you are right. my bad

Comment: @Peter Leimbigler. John Cena part was my mistake. Just fixed it. I guess people who made it did not think this through. It's the only thing I have and I can't change it.

Answer (score 2):

Merge on the first part of the name + team_id, then map the indicator values:

```
df2 = df[['sender', 'team_id']].rename(columns={'sender': 'receiver'})
df2['receiver'] = df2.receiver.str.split().str[0]
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates()  # So left merge preserves size.

df = df.merge(df2, how='left', indicator='btwn_team')
df['btwn_team'] = df.btwn_team.map({'both': 'Yes', 'left_only': 'No'})
```

Output:

```
              sender  team_id  receiver btwn_team
0          John Cena        1  Margaret       Yes
1       Genghis Khan        2  Mahathma        No
2    Mahathma Gandhi        1      John       Yes
3           John Doe        2   Genghis       Yes
4  Margaret Thatcher        1      John       Yes
```